# Is there any way to hide certain windows in Task View (Win+TAB) in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, user-interface

This is probably not possible, but if there is a way, I would like to know about it:

When I use Task View (Win+TAB) there are often a lot of windows which are not useful to me by being there.  An example would be Sticky Notes.

Is there any way, possibly by a registry edit or similar, of hiding specific applications from being visible on Task View?

Answer (score 1):

There are alternatives to the Windows task switcher that allow you to exclude individual windows and entire programs.

[alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/switcher/)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to exclude windows from Alt-Tab or Winkey-Tab is to close the application. I do this so these applications (lesser used, say) do not show up with the two main task switchers.

Answer (score 0):

One way to consider that these apps should be hidden due to lack of value or use by the computer owner is to remove the characteristic that caused them to start. Different programs will be started when the computer boots in different ways.

If the program appears in the system tray (area near the clock) you may be able to right click to open a utility menu, in which you may be able to find settings to disable the auto-start. Similarly, open the undesired program and seek for an entry for Settings or Preferences, in which you may be able to disable auto-start.

One can also remove the program using the uninstall feature for Windows or the uninstall feature often installed when the program is installed.